# Xcode icon files array issue

Tags: xcode

Reading this beginner book and i run in to small problem
changing the default icon to new one.
my problem i cant find the icon files array inside the `plist` file.

where can i find it?
or how do i add it to the `plist` file?

[image: 1]

i try to add it myself but the icon did not change
right click add icon file 
all so try icon files

anyone run in to this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just drag your icon file to the box at the bottom of the image. It is pretty straight forward process. Which Xcode version are you using?

[image]

Comment: thx that workt i am useing 4.6.3  and i was just following the book didnt know there was easyer way :) so thx agin